# calculating % in android

Tags: android

Calculating % of downloaded file:

```
int f = (a*100)/b;
```

But when i get 49% the next step i get `-49%` (with minus)
Why cant get it?

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? int filePercentage = currentBytes/totalBytes * 100 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using `int`s to store your file sizes and creating an arithmetic overflow.  With your code as written, this will fail once the downloaded file is over about 20MB.

Use this:

```
long totalFileSize;
long downloadedBytes;

// ...

int percentageDownloaded = (downloadedBytes * 100) / totalFileSize;
```